# Camera stopped working on Pixel XL

Tags: camera, google-pixel

I have a Pixel XL. The camera stopped working recently. I can't take any pictures. I have tried resetting the cache, rebooting into safe mode, uninstalling new apps, nothing seems to be working. I was able to get this from a bug request:

> 2018-03-02 18:00:49 system_app_crash (text, 990 bytes) Process:
>   com.google.android.GoogleCamera PID: 25738 Flags: 0x30dbbcc5 Package:
>   com.google.android.GoogleCamera v41362666 (5.1.018.177470874)
>   Foreground: Yes Build: google/marlin/marlin:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.016/4503492:user/release-keys
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at iae.run(PG:2)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at iya.b(PG:39)
>       at cqk.a(PG:7)
>       at cts.a(PG:5)
>       at csk.A(PG:577)
>       at csk.f(PG:370)
>       at bua.c(PG:515)
>       at fro.a(PG:3)
>       at frm.a(PG:15)
>       at bua.D(PG:430)
>       at buw.c(PG:18)
>       at buw.b(PG:7)
>       at bvu.run(PG:7)
>       ... 7 more

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: You could try reflashing it maybe. Try LineageOS.  I'm not sure why but no standard OSs seems to work differently sometimes.

Comment: I really dont want to reinstall the os. It was working at one point, but now its not working.